# Another optimization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I am having trouble figuring out a next step in an optimization problem

the question is to find the max and min values of $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{2+x^2+y^2}$

I calculated $f_x$ and $f_y$ and set both them equal to zero, and the only possibility you get is x=y. I dont know how else to find it after this. But the back of the book says the answer is a max at $f(1,1)$ and a min at $f(-1,-1)$ but I dont know how?

$$f_x=\frac{-x^2-2xy+y^2+2}{(2+x^2+y^2)^2}$$

$$f_y= \frac{-y^2-2xy+x^2+2}{(2+x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Can anyone see why please?

Thankyou

Comment: Why don't you post what you got for $f_x$ and $f_y$ so we can check your algebra?

Comment: Once you know that any local minima and maxima have $x = y$, then you've reduced to checking for maxima and minima of the function
$$
g(x) = f(x, x) = \frac{2x}{2 + 2x^2} = \frac{x}{1 + x^2}
$$

Comment: If you substitute $y=x$ into $f_x=0$, you get that $x^2=1$ so $x=\pm1$.

Comment: @user84413 I see, thanks. And arthur, thank you as well can you also please elaborate on that?

Comment: @user84413  Thankyou! I see now. So would I now test $f(1,1)$ and $f(-1,-1)$ ?

Comment: I thought that is what I did, because when I solved or the way Arthur pointed out is how I found my values of x>

Comment: @user84413  If not I am not sure. Wouldnt testing just those give me the values?

Comment: My previous comment wasn't quite right - now you can use the second partial derivatives test to determine if f has local extrema at (1,1) and (-1,-1), but checking for the extrema of the function g(x) won't necessarily give you the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ gives $-x^2-2xy+y^2+2=0$ and $-y^2-2xy+x^2+2=0$, so

subtracting these equations gives $2y^2-2x^2=0, \;\;y^2=x^2,\; $ and so $y=\pm x$.

1) If $y=x$, substituting into the first equation gives $x^2=1$ so $x=\pm 1$.

2) If $y=-x$, substituting into the first equation gives $x^2=-1$, so there is no real solution.

Therefore $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are the only critical points.

---

Since $\;\displaystyle f_{xx}=(2+x^2+y^2)^{-2}(-2x-2y)-4x(-x^2-2xy+y^2+2)(2+x^2+y^2)^{-3}$,

$\;\displaystyle \hspace{.36 in}f_{xy}=(2+x^2+y^2)^{-2}(-2x+2y)-4y(-x^2-2xy+y^2+2)(2+x^2+y^2)^{-3}$,

$\;\displaystyle \hspace{.36 in}f_{yy}=(2+x^2+y^2)^{-2}(-2y-2x)-4y(-y^2-2xy+x^2+2)(2+x^2+y^2)^{-3}$,

A) $\;D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2=(-\frac{1}{4})(-\frac{1}{4})-0^2=\frac{1}{16}>0\;$ and $\;f_{xx}=-\frac{1}{4}<0$ at $(1,1)$,

$\hspace{1.4 in}$so $f$ has a relative maximum at $(1,1)$.

B) $\;D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-(f_{xy})^2=(\frac{1}{4})(\frac{1}{4})-0^2=\frac{1}{16}>0\;$ and $\;f_{xx}=\frac{1}{4}>0$ at $(-1,-1)$,

$\hspace{1.4 in}$so $f$ has a relative minimum at $(-1,-1)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really did help. However, it said ideally to not use the second deravative test and that apparently it can be done without it?

Comment: Also, how can we figure out the difference between relative min and max and total min and max?

Comment: I will add another answer that does not use the second derivative test.

Comment: @user84412 thanks, and I saw the other answer as well which is good, I am still wondering how you knew the difference between relative and global max/min?

Comment: The first answer shows that these are relative extrema, so you would then have to show that the function cannot have a value larger than 1/2 or less than -1/2 to conclude that they were global extrema.  The second answer shows that 1/2 and -1/2 are the largest and smallest values the function can attain, so they are the global extrema.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting $\displaystyle \frac{x+y}{2+x^2+y^2}=t\;\;$ gives $\;\;tx^2-x+ty^2-y+2t=0$.

This will have a solution for $x$ if $b^2-4ac=1-4t(ty^2-y+2t)\ge0$,

which gives $\;\;4t^2y^2-4ty+8t^2-1\le0$.

This will have a solution for $y$ if $b^2-4ac=16t^2-16t^2(8t^2-1)\ge0$.

Then $16t^2(2-8t^2)\ge0,\;\;$ so $8t^2\le2\implies t^2\le\frac{1}{4}\implies-\frac{1}{2}\le t\le \frac{1}{2}$.

Since $t=\frac{1}{2}\implies x^2+y^2-2x-2y+2=0\implies (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=0\implies x=1 \text{ and } y=1$

and $t=-\frac{1}{2}\implies x^2+y^2+2x+2y+2=0\implies (x+1)^2+(y+1)^2=0\implies x=-1 \text{ and } y=-1$,

$f(1,1)=\frac{1}{2}$ is the maximum value for f and $f(-1,-1)=-\frac{1}{2}$ is the minimum value for f.